# select rows with same id but with different column values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to select data with different rows but with same id.

```
| Codenum | Letter | description |
|     001 | A      | APPLES      |
|     002 | A      | BANANA      |
|     001 | B      | RED         |
|     001 | B      | GREEN       |
|     002 | B      | BLUE        |
|     002 | B      | YELLOW      |
```

What i would like is to get the rows that are classified as LETTER B but also the description of LETTER A with the same Codenum.

The incomplete query is `SELECT description FROM table where letter = B`and i want to add the description of letter A that corresponds with the Codenum
desired result :

```
001    B   RED     APPLES
001    B   GREEN   APPLES
002    B   BLUE    BANANA
002    B   YELLOW  BANANA
```

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Just join the table to itself

Comment: it says not unique table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select a.codenum, a.letter, a.description, b.description
from table a join table b 
   on b.codenum = a.codenum 
      and b.letter = 'A'
where a.letter = 'B'
```

Comment: hi. they were on the same tables

Comment: @OFBrc Nothing about the answer provided contradicts that fact.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a subselect:

```
SELECT Codenum, Letter, description, (SELECT description FROM mytable x where x.Codenum = second.Codenum AND Letter = 'A') AS adescription
FROM mytable second
WHERE mytable.Letter = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Try out this query :

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(`description`) as description_concat
FROM
    `table_name`
WHERE
    `letter` = 'B'
GROUP BY
    `letter`
```

Answer (score 0):

Exact Query :

```
select a.codenum, a.letter, a.description,b.description
from tbl_data a join tbl_data b on b.codenum = a.codenum 
and b.letter = 'A' where a.letter = 'B'
```